# How to compare plant response to stress?

Tags: mixed-model, biostatistics, treatment-effect, blup

I am looking for advice on analysis of a greenhouse experiment.

I had 3 levels of stress (drought) treatments, and seeds were from 4 enviromental "Sources".  I grew 5 plants per "Line", approx 10 Lines were from each Source.

I measured initial and final diam and heights of all plants, then dried them and got weights of roots, stems, and leaves, in g.

1. I would like to know how the treatments affected growth of the plants, ie ht, diam, volume, totalweight, proportion of root to total, etc.

I have created some mixed models of each "trait", for example y=totalweight, using "Treatment" as fixed effect with Line as random effect. Line is nested in Source, and Im interested if there if an effect of source on y, Im not sure how to include source in mixed models.

I used these models to get BLUPs for traits for each Line. I am confused how to interpret these in terms of treatment effect though. I am guessing that each Line BLUP would be added to the mean Treatment effect coefficient to predict y? Then the predicted value of the trait would be expressed as, eg TotalMass in High drought. Advice and guidance would be appreciated.

2. Im also curious how these "traits" correlate, I plotted and looked at cor() for pairs of numeric variables, but Im confused especially about the proportional measures.  Id like to know how the treatment affected the proportion of eg leaf weight of totalweight ~ total weight. These did seem to be significant correlations, but is there an issue with using proportions like this?  Or a better way to look at/ graph proportions of plant parts in each treatment?
3. Because Im interested in plants that are tolerant to stress, I computed a response measure that looks at the effect of treatment vs control, ie HtGrowth.Response = (*htGrowthtreatment-*htGrowthcontrol)/(*htGrowthcontrol)
   *mean of 5 plants per Line per treatment.  This allows Lines and Sources to be sorted by this measure, but it seems like I lose info when I used averages, so Im wondering if theres a better way to do this.

I am learning statistics and R as I go and grateful for any advice and suggestions, even if it is to go elsewhere.

Please let me know if I need to clarify - my knowledge is fuzzy so Im not sure if Im asking the right questions.

Comment: It's unclear whether you are interested in the fixed treatment effects, or in the random (Line) effects. You can estimate both with a mixed model. It's also unclear what your questions are. If you want to get some advice about the model and how to extract the estimates, then you'll need provide those details.

Comment: Im sorry for my unclear questions, Im interested in traits that have to do with drought response like height growth and proportion of roots, and wondering the best ways to look at variation of these traits with different levels of stress, and also whether there seem to be correlations or tradeoffs among the traits and among seed sources, in the experimental environments. I am able to extract the estimates from mixed models, but not sure about my model structure (ie seed source as FE?) I asked in part 3 of my question about making a response variable like treatment/control to rank the Lines.

Comment: It seems that you have both questions about how to formulate your scientific hypotheses precisely, and questions about the statistical procedure you are using. The science questions are challenging to answer without domain knowledge. If you have questions about the model structure, then you have to show the model, some of the data and the output from fitting the model to your data.

Comment: Thank you!  Part of my question has to do with comparing proportions, eg totalwt ~ root proportion "do plants with proportionally large roots correlate with plants with larger totalwt?"   This seems similar to a response variable (treated/control), that is a ratio.  Can I rank Lines by this response variable then correlate with other traits?  Id only have one value per Line.  (avg of 5 plants per treatment)

Comment: I can't answer your science questions because I don't understand the setup. It might be way more productive to discuss these questions with your advisor, other peers and professors in your program, etc. Also look at how similar plant experiments have been analyzed before, in articles and books.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I was hoping for some help with this analysis or even just a link to a better place to ask, like one more focused on plant breeding.  Im interested in both the treatment effects and genotype effects, and characterizing these plastic "traits" in different environments (treatments).  The goal being to help inform selection of genotypes to be planted in particular environmental conditions.  I was thinking of editing my question with more details but should I instead delete it?

Comment: It's up to you whether you want to edit your question. From the point of you of someone who doesn't know anything about plant breeding, your questions are difficult to follow. They are not really about the statistical details but about the science (which is why you should to talk to people who know about plant breeding). I'm not sure this forum is the right place to give you scientific guidelines and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a domain knowledge in your field. But from what I understood you want to evaluate the effects of two categorical variables "Treatment" and "Source" on a trait like height (and other traits). Please correct me if I am wrong. By "line" if you literally mean the lines in which plants are planted sequentially (this is my understanding from a crop field), then I don't see how that matters to be included in the model. What's the difference if a plant is planted in line one versus another one in the vicinity line?

For evaluation of the difference between categorical variables with respect to a target variable, ANOVA is commonly used. But I would prefer using the lm() function in R and fit a LR model. So here is how I do it:

```
# ---- simulating some data ------
# Sources: 1 , 2
# Treatments: A, B
# Lines: y,z

A1y = rnorm(100 ,10, 2)
A1z = rnorm(100 ,10, 2)
A2y = rnorm(100 ,10, 2)
A2z = rnorm(100 ,10, 2)

B1y = rnorm(100 ,0, 2)
B1z = rnorm(100 ,0, 2)
B2y = rnorm(100 ,10, 2)
B2z = rnorm(100 ,0, 2)


df = data.frame(trait = c(A1y, A1z, A2y, A2z, B1y, B1z, B2y, B2z),
                group = c(rep('A1y',100), 
                          rep('A1z',100),
                          rep('A2y',100), 
                          rep('A2z',100),
                          rep('B1y',100),
                          rep('B1z',100),
                          rep('B2y',100),
                          rep('B2z',100)))


lm.fit = lm(trait ~ -1 + group, data = df)
GGally::ggcoef_model(lm.fit)
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks verymuch! by Line, I mean a group of plants that are half-siblings, and I would like to look at how the traits vary among Lines and under drought stress in the different treatments.  There were 5 plants per Line per treatment, in a random complete block design.  Each Line is from a geographic Source so Line can be nested in Source.  There was a significant effect of edge, where plants were on the edge of blocks.  I included this as a fixed effect but didnt want to complicate my question. I would like to fit a mixed model to include the effects of Treatment and Source and Line on traits.

Comment: I think it would really help if you could include a chunk of your dataset (maybe use str(df) and share it here). But I think you can fit a random intercept model using the code I shared above. You just need to extend it a bit by adding Lines categories similar to treatment and source and then add the edge values. Does that make sense?

Comment: One goal of this is to screen/rank the Lines for their responses to drought stress.  For example - what Lines grew the most and least in high drought, compared to growth in control?  What Lines had the largest /smallest proportion of roots?  Do these traits correlate?

Comment: Ok, I edited my solution and added a plot to compare each combination of line-source-treatment. Is it cleat?